# How to move branch in SourceTree into Folder?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have the following branch structure in git:

```
master 
feature-2
bugfix/bug-1
feature/feature-1
```

Now I want to move branch `feature-2` into the `feature` folder.

How do I move branches into folders? Either via SourceTree or the git command line.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

SourceTree seems to display "folders" for branches that have the same `folder/structure` in their branch names.

You should simply create a new branch called `feature/feature-2` pointing at the same commit as your current `feature-2` branch. Then push the new branch and delete the old one.

> You can name your branches in a folder structure-like format and they appear as folders in SourceTree. For example you could name it as `features/issue_1539` and SourceTree will display `features` as a folder.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/200282/sourcetree-categorize-branches

Answer (score 32):

You can rename this branch:

```
git branch -m feature-2 feature/feature-2
```

You can also create new branch and delete the old one:

```
git checkout feature-2
git checkout -b feature/feature-2
git branch -d feature-2
```